# Автопостинг в социальные сети

Tags: twitter, facebook, вконтакте

Всем привет.

Есть задание реализовать автопостинг в 3 социальные сети (ВК, фейсбук и твиттер).

Я нашел вот такой [класс для постинга в ВК](http://blog.lalf.ru/2011/09/blog-post_10.html) 
(его еще не проверял)

Подскажите, есть ли что-то подобное для фейсбука и твиттера?

Или может сервис, который можно прикрутить к самописному форуму? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Гугл быстро все нашел: [кросспостинг в twitter, facebook, livejournal, vkontakte](http://habrahabr.ru/post/131107/).

По поводу твитера [здесь](http://dontforget.pro/php/krossposting-v-twitter-sredstvami-api-na-php/) статья. Ну и не забывайте что на [гитхабе есть поиск](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=crossposting). Или возьмите из уже готовых скриптов и сделайте свой: [Social Crossposting](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/social-web/social-share/social-crossposting) - Joomla, [Social Networks Auto-Poster](https://wordpress.org/plugins/social-networks-auto-poster-facebook-twitter-g/) - WP

Answer (score 0):

Если вам не важно получить умения и знания для автопостинга в несколько социальных сетей, то наибыстрейшем, пожалуй, способом, будет следующий:

1. Прикручиваете RSS к самописному форуму
2. Используете сервис [IFTTT](http://ifttt.com/) для автопостинга RSS-ленты в Facebook и Twitter
3. Для автопостинга в ВК используете другое решение
4. ?????
5. PROFIT!